# How do you change the paper size on pdf export in emacs?

Tags: org-mode, spacemacs

Every time I export using the dispatcher, the pdf that is produced is letter size. My system and printer are A4.

How do I change the paper size for pdf (and text) exports in emacs?

Answer (score 2):

```
#+LATEX_HEADER: \usepackage[a4paper,text={6.25in,9in}, truedimen]{geometry}
```

works for me.

Comment: Ah, I just re-read your post. What do you mean by "and text"?

Comment: Please elaborate. Explain how/why this answers the question.

Comment: The poster uses the phrase "I export using the dispatcher, the pdf .." It seems reasonable to assume - in the absence of other information - that the poster is using org-mode. If he is using org-mode then he will be familiar with LATEX_HEADER. In this context, my answer seems reasonable to me. Perhaps you can supply a more extensive answer.

Comment: Thanks for the response. Firstly, the "and text" is that I very often print from emacs (yes orgmode) and A4 is not the default as per my computer region setting. Everything defaults to letter. This is what I'm trying to change. Normally I print to PDF for use on my iPad. I will try the latex header, thank you.

Comment: Tried this and it still produces Letter size. I'm using the Pandoc export in dispatcher. Tried both ms and latex export.

Comment: Please move all such helpful explanation from your comment to the answer. Comments can be deleted at any time.